# Navigation menu lacks a "Partners" link

Tags: bug, user-interface

The navigation menu at the top of http://www.ubuntu.com has items

- [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/)
- [Community](http://community.ubuntu.com/)
- [Ask!](https://askubuntu.com/)
- [Developer](http://developer.ubuntu.com/)
- [Design](https://design.ubuntu.com/)
- [Discourse](http://discourse.ubuntu.com/)
- [Hardware](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification)
- [Insights](https://insights.ubuntu.com/)
- [Juju](https://jujucharms.com/)
- [**Partners**](http://partners.ubuntu.com/)
- [Shop](http://shop.ubuntu.com/)
- More ›

However, since the "Partners" item is missing from the Ask Ubuntu menu, the illusion of integration is broken.